# Find derivative using the definition of the derivative as a limit

Tags: limits, derivatives

$$f(x) = \frac{1} {\sqrt{x}}$$

find $f'(x)$ using the definition of the derivative as a limit.

I know that

$$
f'(x) = \frac{(x + \delta)^{-1/2} - (x)^{-1/2}}{\delta} 
$$

as $\delta$ goes to $0$.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
\begin{align*}
f'(x) & = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{(x + \delta)^{-1/2} - (x)^{-1/2}}{\delta}\\
& = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x+\delta}}{\delta \sqrt{x(x+\delta)}}\\
& = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x+\delta}}{\delta \sqrt{x(x+\delta)}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+\delta}}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+\delta}}\right)\\
\end{align*}